# How to suspend a specific thread in kernel?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, kernel

Is there a way to suspend and resume a thread (what is created by a thread class exists from java) using KID in the kernel? I was thinking of something like pthread_kill, but that function doesn't work at kernel level. Please tell me how to do it per thread, not per process. (Unfortunately, per-process pause/resume works fine through the kill() function. but what I want is per thread, not per process.)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way to do that without code changes and without exposing this as option to control externally.

If you decide to introduce code changes that will manage the thread state read first here  about deprecated methods Thread.suspend and resume and follow the proposed examples:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html